# Why everything word-wrap inside an absolute element nested inside a float or inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have this portion of style, a relative inline-block element with an absolute element inside it:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;position: relative">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

A circumstance not too unusual either, that can be seen in a CSS dropdown menu but instead of using `float:left` to `li` elements, you use `display:inline-block`.

Why in this specific case, inputs inside the absolute block are wrapped? And if you try to remove, one of the property assigned (from the position to the display) it doesn't wrap suddenly? And how can be resolved without changing the style structure?

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;position: relative">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and browsers ignore a closing slash in HTML. It has no meaning and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element with `position:absolute` has a *shrink-to-fit* behavior. you can notice the same think if you write a long sentence and it will break on each word:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;position: relative">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    aaaa bbb ccc ddd  eee fff
  </div>
</div>
```

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate **the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks**. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm. Thirdly, calculate the available width: this is found by solving for 'width' after setting 'left' (in case 1) or 'right' (in case 3) to 0.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

The *available width* will be 0 in this case because the containing block is `inline-block` (its width is 0 since its only child element is removed from the flow), so the `max` will be the *preferred minimum width* and the *preferred width* will for sure be bigger thus we will end with the *preferred minimum width*.

---

Removing `inline-block` or `position:relative` will change either the width of the containing block or the containing block thus the *available width* will change and it will get picked instead of the *preferred minimum width* since in both cases we will end with a `block` element as a containing block.

Using `float:left` instead of `inline-block` will create the same output because float will have a width equal to 0 also:

```html
<div style="float:left;position: relative">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    aaaa bbb ccc ddd  eee fff
  </div>
</div>
```

An easy way to avoid this is to use `white-space:nowrap` to avoid all possible line breaks and the *preferred minimum width* will simply be equal to the *preferred width.*

```html
<div style="float:left;position: relative">
  <div style="position:absolute,white-space:nowrap;">
    aaaa bbb ccc ddd  eee fff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. That's why removing `position:relative` works normally since it will take html width, and removing `display:inline-block` the div width stretch and it will take div width.

Comment: @Keaire exactly :)

Comment: Using `width: max-content` seems resolving also the "issue" if you want the absolute element fit the content instead of specify a fixed width.

Comment: @Keaire no, use `white-space:nowrap`