# Why are the results of img width different in some browsers? Who is correct?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

This has a demo:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;">
   <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/iQ2rVup.jpg"
      style="width:100%;height:100px;"
   />
</div>
```

[On Codepen](https://codepen.io/aaronbird/full/KYjYwJ)

Chrome result:
[image]

Firefox/IE result:
[image]

I saw the W3C document.
Absolutely locate non-displaced elements are calculated as follows.

```
min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

Is the result of chrome wrong?

Comment: the issue is that both can be explained but not sure which one should be the correct one. The last one is surely more intuitive and logical, it's all about the `width:100%` (here is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973569/8620333)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>This will probably not answer the question but I will try to explain what is happening with chrome and why both can be correct.</sup>

First, you should notice that the same happen even if you consinder `inline-block` element or `float` as they are also shrink-to-fit elements

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
   <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/iQ2rVup.jpg"
      style="width:100%;height:100px;"
   />
</div>
<br>
<div style="float:left;">
   <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/iQ2rVup.jpg"
      style="width:100%;height:100px;"
   />
</div>
```

Now it's all about the `width:100%`. Since it's a percentage value, the reference will be the width of the containing block but our containing block is a shrink-to-fit element which means that its width depend on its content. Here we have a kind of cycle.

Here is the part of [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#percentage-sizing) that describe such behavior:

> Sometimes the size of a percentage-sized box’s containing block depends on the intrinsic size contribution of the box itself, creating a cyclic dependency. When calculating the containing block’s size, **the percentage behaves as auto**. Then, unless otherwise specified, when calculating the used sizes and positions of the containing block’s contents: ...

So basically, we consider the width of our image to be `auto`, we calculate the width of the `div` (parent element) and then we use `width:100%` again on that calculated width.

Here come the difference. Firefox is considering the height set to the image in the calculation to find the value of the width of the image (as described in this part of [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width)). Now that we have the *new* width of the image, the parent element will shrint-to-fit this width and we will reconsider the `width:100%` again based on the previous width.

Chrome is setting the width to auto BUT is not considering the height and in this case the width will use the intrinsic dimension of the image to have the following:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
   <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/iQ2rVup.jpg"
      style="/*width:100%;height:100px;*/"
   />
</div>
```

Now that we have the *new* width, we can calculate the width of the parent element (shrink-to-fit) and now if we set `width:100%;height:100px` to the image we wil have `100px` for height and `100%` of the containing block width which is the initial image width.

---

Now the question is: should we consider the height  to calculate the value of *new* width of the image when this one is considered as `auto` in order to calculate the width of the containing block? If no Chrome is correct, if yes Firefox is correct.

---

Worth to note that in both cases the image may get distored. We don't notice this on Firefox in the actual example because the height is small.

Here is an animation to illustrate the distortion and to show the different behavior between both browsers.

```css
img {
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
}

.wrapper {
 border:2px solid;
 animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border:2px solid green;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width:500px;
  }
  to {
    width:100px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iQ2rVup.jpg"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

The `wrapper` here is used as the containing block of our shrink-to-fit element and will define the *available width*. We can clearly see that in Chrome the image is always distored and in Firefix the distortion will happen later.

Comment: I have a question about Chrome.
Why is the container not larger than the viewport when the img is very large.
This is a demo: https://codepen.io/aaronbird/pen/zXgOzP

Comment: @Bob here it becomes more funny :) ... so as I described the image will have the width auto to define the width of the containing block ( you have a large width now) but the width of the position:absolute is a shrink-to-fit and if you check the formula that you shared in your question you have `available-width` and here we consider the containing block of the absolute element which is the viewport to define the available width which is the screen width ... now if you apply the min/max logic you will have that width.

Comment: @Bob To make it easier, a shrink-to-fit element will fit its content but will not grow more than the width availble to it that is defined by the containing block (it can be more complex in other situation)

Comment: @Bob here is an easy example with text to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/cmf1x0y5/ .. another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347032/8620333

Comment: According to this [demo](https://codepen.io/aaronbird/pen/zXgOzP).  
The original width of the image is 3999px and the viewport width is 1366px.  
so, div's shrink-to-fit width = min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width) = min(max(3999, 1366), 3999) = 3999.  
I think the result should be 1366.Where do I understand wrong?

Comment: @Bob the tricky one is the *preferred minimum width* which is not the same as *preferred width* ... I agree that this one is a bit complex, even the spec don't define this clearly but basically this width is the minumum width possible to contain the data and since we are dealing with an image I guess it's equal to 0. what I know for sure is that this width should be in most of the cases the smallest one, for text it's easy to find: it's the width of the longest word (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/kjprLo26/). I will try to invesitage and see If I find some accurate details.

Comment: @Bob I have edited my answer to include more details about this behavior as I notice another intresting fact and this also have to do with the available width and prefered min width

Comment: You are right, the preferred minimum width is 0.
I wrote a demo to determine this.  https://codepen.io/aaronbird/pen/PgMVMw