# How is the baseline determined for the content of grid items?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This has really got me confused. See the two demos below:

```html
<div style="display: grid; align-items: baseline; gap: 10px; grid-template-columns: 160px minmax(100px, 200px) auto;">
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row name
      </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <button style="height:30px">
              First row description
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row description
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8m2cujvg/

```html
<div style="display: grid; align-items: baseline; gap: 10px; grid-template-columns: 160px minmax(100px, 200px) auto;">
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row name
      </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <button style="height:30px">
              First row description
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row description
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8m2cujvg/1/

You can see that the first one has an issue with text alignment. I tried looking through the docs: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#alignment-baseline but struggle to see any differentiation between block and inline-block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*"I struggle to see any differentiation between block and inline-block."*

The difference is that inline level elements activate the `vertical-align` property.

So in your span with `display: inline-block`, a `vertical-align: baseline` rule is applied by default. This sets the content of the span to the baseline of the parent.

The `vertical-align` property has no effect on block level elements.

> The vertical-align CSS property sets vertical alignment of an inline,
> inline-block or table-cell box. ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

The solution is to override the default. Add this to your code:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div style="display: grid; align-items: baseline; gap: 10px; grid-template-columns: 160px minmax(100px, 200px) auto;">
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row name
      </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <button style="height:30px">
              First row description
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column-start: 1;">
    <span>
        First row description
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="grid-column: 2 / 4;">
    <div>
      <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see so really my fix to change things to block was just accidental. I have tried vertical-align: top and this does seem to work. Could you explain a bit more how this property interracts with the baseline alignment setting on the grid? I know you mentioned that baseline is the default on an inline block and this sets the content of the span to the baseline of the parent but why is the baseline different in the 2 examples?

Answer (score 0):

You will get surprised but it seems you discovered a bug in Chromium based browsers (Chrome and Edge) because both your output behave the same in Firefox.

This is logically a bug because whataver the alignment, the output should never produce an overlap or an overflow especially that you didn't specify any explicit height or any template row so this is definitely a bug.

Comment: @DeanR don't have Opera so it's also a bug there then. Probably the same algorithm is used by many browsers creating this bug