# unexpected behavior with grid-template-rows and 1fr on chrome

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to build a grid with 2 rows inside a flex column. The flex container has a minimum height to fill the window. The first line of the grid should fill the available space, so I was thinking of the *fr* unit. A simplified version may look like that:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.grid > * {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>some title</h1>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine with firefox:

[image: test on firefox]

But not with chrome:

[image: test on chrome]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid container is interpreting the `min-height: 100vh` on the flex parent differently in Chrome and Firefox.

As you noted, in Firefox everything works as you expect. But in Chrome, the `min-height` is effectively ignored (even though `flex-grow: 1` works on the same element).

If you switch to `height: 100vh` you'll see the `1fr` work in Chrome, as well.

I would have to research more to tell you if this is a bug or not.

Consider nesting the grid inside another grid, as opposed to flex, container.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}

.grid {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>some title</h1>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9frq4zLj/)

Comment: indeed, nesting the grid inside a grid instead of a flex container also solved the problem. I will also do some research to find if this is a bug. Please let me know if you find something. thx :)

Comment: @rgmt I also vote for a bug (like here too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67332926/8620333) and I got the confirmation that the grid layout is buggy and being reworked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67011770/8620333