# How position absolute and fixed block elements get their dimension?

Tags: html, css

actually I saw many questions like this but I can't found normal answer of this question because that I open this question again.

When we have block element(display: block) this element contain full width of parent component if element itself root element this element width take 100%.

But when we look block element(display:block) but position absolute elements there are work like inline-block elements(work like block element but width not full of parent component) even parent element position relative.

Can anyone explain me why position absolute and fixed elements width not work like display: block elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/epbkmzh3/28/

```
    <div class="container">
      <div style="background: red;"> 1 </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
      <div style="position: absolute; background: red;"> 1 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Specification detailing how you can find the width/height of any element: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html

From there you can read for absolute element that:

> The constraint that determines the used values for these elements is:
>
> `'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block`

Then

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then, if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static position and apply rule number three below; otherwise, set 'right' to the static position and apply rule number one below.

And the rule number three:

> 'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then **the width is shrink-to-fit** . Then solve for 'right'

*The rule number one is also similar*

And if you continue reading you will find how to calculate the *shrink-to-fit* width. You will also notice that the same *shrink-to-fit* algorithm apply to `float` and `inline-block` element

---

Also note that fixed element is a particular case of absolute so the same rule applies. The only difference is the containing block

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport.  <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)</sup>

---

You can also see that block elements follow almost the same constraint (without left/right) but [the rules are different](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> `'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`

Then

> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and 'width' follows from the resulting equality.

This will make `width = width of containing block`

---

An important difference between inline-block element is that absolute element will not take the width of their content like we may think. This happen in most of the case due to the constraint explained above but check the below example:

```css
.container {
 clear:left;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float:left;position:relative;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; background: red;"> 1 1 1 1 1 1  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="float:left;position:relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; background: red;"> 1 1 1 1 1 1  </div>
</div>
```

Note how the absolute element will wrap to the smallest size possible unline the inline-block. This is due to the fact that the containing block is also a *shrink-to-fit*  container.

Related: [Why everything word-wrap inside an absolute element nested inside a float or inline-block element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54346873/8620333)

Comment: Thanks for response but I don't understand this part '  'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block  '. You mean left and right propeties values change width of position absolute element?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev yes they do. Try to set left:0 and right:0 and your absolute element will be full width of its container ... the width of absolute is not as easy as you may think and if you check the link I shared you will see a lot of cases based on either you specify some properties or not. By default you didn't specify anything so they are auto and I highlighted the rule that apply in case everything is auto. In the other cases, you need to follow the adequate rule

Comment: Thank U so much. I will read this link. You help me today so much :)

Comment: @MuradSofiyev welcome, take the time to read it many times because it's not trivial to understand everything from the first reading.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `absolute` and `fixed` positioning removes the element from document flow.

And since those elements are removed from document flow, there is no reference for what width they should be, so they only take as much space as their content.

They are still "block" elements if they are inherently block elements (`div`, `p`, etc.), unless the display property is changed via CSS. **Edit for clarity**: The browser will still compute as `display: block` even if the display property is changed via CSS.

Here is some documentation on document flow:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/In_Flow_and_Out_of_Flow

The important part:

> Taking an item out of flow
>
> All elements are in-flow apart from:
>
> - floated items
> - items with position: absolute (including position: fixed which acts in the same way)
> - the root element (html)
>
> Out of flow items create a new Block Formatting Context (BFC) and therefore everything inside them can be seen as a mini layout, separate from the rest of the page. The root element therefore is out of flow, as the container for everything in our document, and establishes the Block Formatting Context for the document.

Comment: *unless the display property is changed via CSS.* --> even if you change the display of absolute/fixed element, it will still compute to block so you cannot really change the display of such elements

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I was merely pointing out that `absolute` and `fixed` element are still block elements - unless you change them. I did not say it would affect how they actually display if you did change it.

Comment: *element are still block elements - unless you change them* --> no you cannot change them :) try to make them display:inline and you will see that the computed value of display is block

Comment: I'm not disagreeing here...yes, it will still be computed as block, that doesn't stop someone from changing the CSS display property to something else - regardless of how the browser interprets it. Will it do anything? No. I'll edit that to be more clear in my intent.

Comment: also concerning this  *And since those elements are removed from document flow, there is no reference for what width they should be, so they only take as much space as their content.* --> inline-block is not removed from the flow but also take as mush space as its content (same for table element)

Comment: That's not the basis of this question and only refers to `absolute` and `fixed` position elements in this case.