# Why does my navbar stay on the left side of the page when i turn it to fixed?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a fixed navbar for my website. When its not fixed it works perfectly fine but when i try to do

```
position: fixed;
```

it messes up and sticks to the left and i couldnt figure out why. Here is the code, Thanks.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13vh;
  background-color: #d6e0e4;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: harlow;
}

.navlinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

.navlinks li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navlinks a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  transition: 250ms;
}
```

```html
:

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">

      <h4>Me</h4>

    </div>
    <ul class="navlinks">

      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tr</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Because `fixed` takes the element out of document flow and it will only be as wide as the content inside of it. And it will always go to the top left of your window unless you set properties for it not to.

Comment: So can i fix it by using just a width property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How position absolute and fixed block elements get their dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62818118/how-position-absolute-and-fixed-block-elements-get-their-dimension)

Comment: Yes, give it a width of `100%` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when you make position fixed it shrinks to wrap it's children and nothing else. you need to set width to your navigation. also i added `margin:0` for body so you can have it without unnecessary whitespace.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* remove margin from body */
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13vh;
  background-color: #d6e0e4;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set full window width; */
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: harlow;
}

.navlinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

.navlinks li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navlinks a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  transition: 250ms;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">

      <h4>Me</h4>

    </div>
    <ul class="navlinks">

      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tr</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`position:fixed` positions your block relative to the page. You need to use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and/or `left` to position it. It also automatically shrinks down to fit its content.

> `fixed`: [...]
> Its final position is determined by the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

> Most of the time, absolutely positioned elements that have `height` and `width` set to `auto` are sized so as to fit their contents.
> However, non-replaced, absolutely positioned elements can be made to fill the available vertical space by specifying both `top` and `bottom` and leaving `height` unspecified (that is, `auto`).
> They can likewise be made to fill the available horizontal space by specifying both `left` and `right` and leaving `width` as `auto`.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning

You're missing either `width: 100%;` or `left: 0; right: 0;` in your `nav` rules.

Comment: Yes as you said 100% width was the problem! Thanks a lot