# Block element inside fixed position <body/> doesn't take up 100% width - why?

Tags: html, css

In most cases `<div>`'s and other block elements take up 100% width of the parent. However if I place `<div>` as a child of `<body>` with `position: fixed` it no longer stretches horizontally. Why?

Note: I'm looking for explanation rather than a fix.

Static position body:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="child">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Fixed position body:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
}

.child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="child">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818336/8620333

Comment: Is it the same situation though? In my example `.child` position is always `static`.

I'm guessing it's something about default `<body>` sizing, but  can't figure it out in detail.

If you set `<div>`(or another element) position to `fixed` it's removed from document's flow, and shrinks to its content width. But if you set `<body>` position to `fixed` it still takes 100% document width.