# Span use max width before line break

Tags: html, css

I've got following setup:

```css
.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim purus et arcu ultrices posuere. Quisque tempus elementum facilisis. Duis vitae enim eu erat elementum dapibus vitae ac eros. Pellentesque faucibus pretium leo in accumsan. Nulla ullamcorper mollis dolor, euismod.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason I can't get the `span` to grow to the defined 300px max-width while breaking once the max-width is reached.

Comment: You only use `max-width` - try it with just `width` and/or `min-width` - you're currently only saying "you can use 300px if you need it" where you seem you want "you can use a minimum of 300px"

Comment: The length of the span can vary it may only be a word on occasion. So I'd like to have a span that could be only 1 word in width. But when another text exceeds the 300px I would like the span to take up multiple lines.

Comment: To which end then, the answer from Sigurd Mazanti is your best bet - absolute positioning isn't the best thing to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such case, use a big negative margin

```css
.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-right:-100vmax
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim purus et arcu ultrices posuere. Quisque tempus elementum facilisis. Duis vitae enim eu erat elementum dapibus vitae ac eros. Pellentesque faucibus pretium leo in accumsan. Nulla ullamcorper mollis dolor, euismod.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related to understand what is happening in your case: [Why everything word-wrap inside an absolute element nested inside a float or inline-block element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54346873/8620333)

Comment: out of curiosity, is it a typo that you have no semicolon after the `margin-right` or is it necessary to leave it out when using `vmax`?

Comment: @tacoshy the semicolon is not mandatory for the last property so we can have it or not. It will change nothing

Answer (score 2):

Is applying `position: absolute` on `container` necessary?

When you use `position: absolute` without a parent element its positioned relative to, it will go out of the document flow. If you apply `position: relative` instead, the `max-width` behaviour will work as intended because its relative to the parent container `container`. By doing it like this, the element will stretch to full width (the `max-width: 300px` that you set) because its container doesnt have a specificed width

**Read more about positioning values**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning

```css
.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim purus et arcu ultrices posuere. Quisque tempus elementum facilisis. Duis vitae enim eu erat elementum dapibus vitae ac eros. Pellentesque faucibus pretium leo in accumsan. Nulla ullamcorper mollis dolor, euismod.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works, but in this specific case I had to have both containers positioned absolute.